# Simplifying a set of repetitive equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to represent the equations below in such format that they can be represented as one. The first two together and the second two as well? (maybe with help of vector representation) The equations come from the article about [least square circle fitting](https://dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf) (equations 2, 3, 4 and 5). I don't really know if that's possible.

\begin{equation}
    \sum\limits_{i}u_i g(u_i, v_i) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \sum\limits_{i}v_i g(u_i, v_i) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    u_c S_{uu} + v_c S_{uv} = \frac{1}{2}(S_{uuu} + S_{uvv})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    u_c S_{uv} + v_c S_{vv} = \frac{1}{2}(S_{vvv} + S_{vuu})
\end{equation}

Note: not sure what tags to use

Comment: Given two equations $x=y$ and $z=w$, you can always write them as the single vector equation $(x,z)=(y,w)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems forced and not pretty, but you could write
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_i u_i g(u_i, v_i) \delta_{i1} + \sum_i v_i g(u_i, v_i) \delta_{i2} &
+ \left[ u_c S_{uu} + v_c S_{uv} \right] \delta_{i3}
+\left[ u_c S_{uv} + v_c S_{vv} \right] \delta_{i4}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(S_{uuu}+ S_{uvv})\delta_{i3} + \frac{1}{2} \left( S_{vvv} + S_{vuu} \right) \delta_{i4}
\end{split}
$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, $j=1, 2,3, 4$.

Comment: That is quite amazing, but I think I did not explain the problem quite well. What I was aiming to achieve is to represent the first two as one and seperately the second two as one. Given the fact that they just differ in variables and indexes.

Comment: Well then you just do it like this:
$$
\sum_i u_i g(u_i, v_i) \delta_{i1} + \sum_i v_i g(u_i, v_i) \delta_{i2} = 0
$$

$$
\left[ u_c S_{uu} + v_c S_{uv} \right] \delta_{i3}
+\left[ u_c S_{uv} + v_c S_{vv} \right] \delta_{i4}
= \frac{1}{2}(S_{uuu}+ S_{uvv})\delta_{i3} + \frac{1}{2} \left( S_{vvv} + S_{vuu} \right) \delta_{i4}
$$